# QTabWidget: close tab button not working

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8, qtabwidget

I have set `ui->tabWidget->setTabsClosable(true);` but `QTabwidget` only showing a cross on each tab that is not closing tab on click on this button. What else I have to do to make tabs closable? I tried to connect any slot (which would be proper for this work) of close to signal `tabCloseRequested(int)` but couldn't find any such slot in tabwidget. Please suggest the right way.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Create a slot e.g. `closeMyTab(int)` and connect the tab widget's `tabCloseRequested(int)` signal to this slot. In this slot call tab widget's `removeTab` method with the index received from the signal.

See [this answer](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17102/#85397) for more details.

Answer (score 9):

For future stumblers upon this question looking for a PyQt5 solution, this can be condensed into a 1-liner:

```
tabs = QTabWidget()
tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(lambda index: tabs.removeTab(index))
```

The tabCloseRequested signal emits an integer equal to the index of the tab that emitted it, so you can just connect it to a lambda function that takes the index as its argument.

The only problem I could see with this is that connecting a lambda function to the slot prevents the object from getting garbage collected when the tab is deleted ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48501804/10342097)).

EDIT (9/7/21): The lambda function  isn't actually necessary since QTabWidget.removeTab takes an integer index as its sole argument by default, so the following will suffice (and avoids the garbage-collection issue):

```
tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(tabs.removeTab)
```

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do it since we got new connection syntax (Qt 5) is:

```
QTabWidget* tabWidet = new QTabWidget();
connect(tabWidget->tabBar(), &QTabBar::tabCloseRequested, tabWidget->tabBar(), &QTabBar::removeTab);
```

Comment: Worked very well on Qt5 indeed. Recommending this solution.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to tell the `tabWidget` itself to close the requested tab index (the param passed to the slot) as this:

```
ui->tabWidget->removeTab(index);
```