# How to properly combine PySide2 and pytransitions for implementing a state machine for GUI application

Tags: python, state-machine, pyside2, pytransitions

Background: I'd like to implement a GUI for controlling a bunch of clients (that talk to 'servers' controlling hardware like motors, cameras etc. via RPC calls) using PySide2.

Previous approach: Typically, what I'd do is to create my GUI and connect the UI signals to the Client slots and the other way round. This works perfectly fine for simpler applications.

Problem: I would like my GUI to represent allowed calls to the clients properly. The most simple example: after executing `client1.doXY()` I'd like to disable the button that executed that command and reactivate it only after `doZY()` is completed. While this is totally possible with the approach above it feels wrong when things get more complicated: e.g. when GUI elements depend on the state of multiple clients.

Approach : I therefore thought I'd be a good idea to use finite state machines as an intermediate layer between the clients and the GUI and came across [pytransitions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions), which looks very promising.
However, I'm struggling finding the right way combining those two worlds.

Questions:

- Is this generally speaking a valid design approach to have such a layer ?
- In particular as shown in the working code example, I have to move the client to a separate thread to avoid the GUI freeze while the client is performing a blocking call. While my code works fine, it requires some overhead in creating additional qt signals to connect the `ClientState` and the `Client` object.
  Can this be done more elegantly (i.e. no additional xy_requested signal, but somehow a direct call from the `ClientState` to the `Client` functions that is still calls the `Client` function in the `Client` thread and not the main thread ?

Working example:

[image: running state machine]

Code:

```
import io
import logging
from time import sleep

import numpy as np
from PySide2 import QtSvg, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, Slot, QObject, QThread
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication
from transitions.extensions import GraphMachine

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


class Client(QObject):
    # Client signals
    sig_move_done = Signal()
    sig_disconnected = Signal()
    sig_connected = Signal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @Slot(int)
    def client_move(self, dest):
        print(f'Client moving to {dest}...')
        sleep(3)  # some blocking function
        if np.random.rand() < 0.5:
            print("Error occurred during movement...")
            self.sig_disconnected.emit()
        else:
            print("Movement done...")
            self.sig_move_done.emit()

    @Slot()
    def client_disconnect(self):
        # do something then...  on success do:
        self.sig_disconnected.emit()

    @Slot()
    def client_connect(self):
        # do something ... on success do:
        self.sig_connected.emit()


# define states, transitions and extra args for transitions state machine:
states = ['ready', 'moving', 'unknown']

transitions = [
    {'trigger': 'move', 'source': 'ready', 'dest': 'moving'},
    {'trigger': 'stopped', 'source': 'moving', 'dest': 'ready'},
    {'trigger': 'disconnect_', 'source': ['ready', 'moving'], 'dest': 'unknown'},
    {'trigger': 'error', 'source': ['ready', 'moving'], 'dest': 'unknown'},
    {'trigger': 'connect_', 'source': 'unknown', 'dest': 'ready'}

]

extra_args = dict(initial='unknown', title='Simple state machine',
                  show_conditions=True, show_state_attributes=True)


class ClientState(QObject):
    # machine signals
    sig_update_available = Signal()
    sig_move_requested = Signal(int)  # can this be avoided ? see self.on_enter_moving
    sig_connect_requested = Signal()  # can this be avoided ? 

    def __init__(self, client, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.client = client
        # move client to seperate thread
        self.worker_thread = QThread()
        self.client.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.start()

        self.machine = GraphMachine(model=self, states=states, transitions=transitions,
                                    show_auto_transitions=False, **extra_args, after_state_change="update_available",
                                    send_event=True)

        # connecting Client signals to state machine triggers
        self.client.sig_disconnected.connect(self.disconnect_)
        self.client.sig_connected.connect(self.connect_)
        self.client.sig_move_done.connect(self.stopped)
        self.update_available = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.sig_update_available.emit()

        # can this be avoided ? see self.on_enter_moving
        self.sig_move_requested.connect(self.client.client_move)
        self.sig_connect_requested.connect(self.client.client_connect)

    def on_enter_moving(self, event):
        print(event.kwargs)
        dest = event.kwargs.get('dest', 0)
        # calling self.client_move() directly will cause self.client_move to be called from main thread...
        # calling it via a helper signal instead:
        self.sig_move_requested.emit(dest)

    def show_graph(self, **kwargs):
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        self.get_graph(**kwargs).draw(stream, prog='dot', format='svg')
        return stream.getvalue()


class GUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, client_state):
        super().__init__()
        self.client_state = client_state

        # setup UI
        self.setWindowTitle("State")
        self.svgWidget = QtSvg.QSvgWidget()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.svgWidget)
        self.btn_move = QPushButton("move")
        self.btn_connect = QPushButton("(re-)connect")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_move)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_connect)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Connect Slots/Signals
        ## machine -> GUI
        self.client_state.sig_update_available.connect(self.update_gui)

        ## GUI --> machine
        self.btn_move.clicked.connect(lambda: self.client_state.move(dest=np.random.randint(1, 100)))
        self.btn_connect.clicked.connect(
            self.client_state.connect_)

        # update UI
        self.update_gui()

    def update_gui(self):
        print("Update model graph and GUI...")
        self.svgWidget.load(self.client_state.show_graph())

        if self.client_state.is_ready():
            self.btn_move.setEnabled(True)
            self.btn_connect.setDisabled(True)
        if self.client_state.is_moving():
            self.btn_move.setDisabled(True)
            self.btn_connect.setDisabled(True)
        if self.client_state.is_unknown():
            self.btn_move.setDisabled(True)
            self.btn_connect.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    client = Client()
    client_state = ClientState(client)
    gui = GUI(client_state)
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is this generally speaking a valid design approach to have such a layer?

Yes, it is valid and in complex applications the FSM is implemented as they simplify the logic.

---

With regard to IMHO simplification, I prefer to verify if there are similar tools in Qt that exist in this case since they interact friendly with the elements of Qt through events or signals. In this case there are at least 2 options:

### The State Machine Framework:

```py
import time
from functools import partial
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import numpy as np


class Client(QtCore.QObject):
    # Client signals
    sig_move_done = QtCore.Signal()
    sig_disconnected = QtCore.Signal()
    sig_connected = QtCore.Signal()

    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def client_move(self, dest):
        print(f"Client moving to {dest}...")
        time.sleep(3)  # some blocking function
        if np.random.rand() < 0.5:
            print("Error occurred during movement...")
            self.sig_disconnected.emit()
        else:
            print("Movement done...")
            self.sig_move_done.emit()

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def client_disconnect(self):
        # do something then...  on success do:
        self.sig_disconnected.emit()

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def client_connect(self):
        # do something ... on success do:
        self.sig_connected.emit()


class GUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("State")

        self.btn_move = QtWidgets.QPushButton("move")
        self.btn_connect = QtWidgets.QPushButton("(re-)connect")

        self.client = Client()
        self._thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self._thread.start()
        self.client.moveToThread(self._thread)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_move)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_connect)
        self.resize(320, 120)

        # states
        self.unknown_state = QtCore.QState()
        self.ready_state = QtCore.QState()
        self.moving_state = QtCore.QState()

        # transitions
        self.ready_state.addTransition(self.btn_move.clicked, self.moving_state)
        self.moving_state.addTransition(self.client.sig_move_done, self.ready_state)
        self.ready_state.addTransition(self.client.sig_disconnected, self.unknown_state)
        self.moving_state.addTransition(self.client.sig_disconnected, self.unknown_state)
        self.unknown_state.addTransition(self.btn_connect.clicked, self.ready_state)
        self.unknown_state.addTransition(self.client.sig_connected, self.ready_state)

        self.unknown_state.entered.connect(self.on_unknown_state_enter)
        self.ready_state.entered.connect(self.on_ready_state_enter)
        self.moving_state.entered.connect(self.on_moving_state_enter)

        state_machine = QtCore.QStateMachine(self)
        state_machine.addState(self.ready_state)
        state_machine.addState(self.moving_state)
        state_machine.addState(self.unknown_state)

        state_machine.setInitialState(self.unknown_state)
        state_machine.start()

    def on_unknown_state_enter(self):
        print("unknown_state")
        self.btn_move.setDisabled(True)
        self.btn_connect.setEnabled(True)

    def on_ready_state_enter(self):
        print("ready_state")
        self.btn_move.setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_connect.setDisabled(True)

    def on_moving_state_enter(self):
        print("moving_state")
        self.btn_move.setDisabled(True)
        self.btn_connect.setDisabled(True)
        dest = np.random.randint(1, 100)
        wrapper = partial(self.client.client_move, dest)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._thread.quit()
        self._thread.wait()
        super().closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = GUI()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### Qt SCXML:

**Simple_State_Machine.scxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" version="1.0" binding="early" xmlns:qt="http://www.qt.io/2015/02/scxml-ext" name="Simple_State_Machine" qt:editorversion="4.10.0" initial="unknown">
    <qt:editorinfo initialGeometry="150.82;359.88;-20;-20;40;40"/>
    <state id="ready">
        <qt:editorinfo stateColor="#ff974f" geometry="425.83;190.46;-60;-50;120;100" scenegeometry="425.83;190.46;365.83;140.46;120;100"/>
        <transition type="internal" event="move" target="moving">
            <qt:editorinfo endTargetFactors="35.02;9.52" movePoint="-34.84;14.59" startTargetFactors="32.33;90.16"/>
        </transition>
        <transition type="internal" event="disconnect" target="unknown">
            <qt:editorinfo endTargetFactors="91.87;60.92" movePoint="9.38;9.36" startTargetFactors="6.25;63.37"/>
        </transition>
    </state>
    <state id="unknown">
        <qt:editorinfo stateColor="#89725b" geometry="150.82;190.46;-60;-50;120;100" scenegeometry="150.82;190.46;90.82;140.46;120;100"/>
        <transition type="internal" target="ready" event="connect">
            <qt:editorinfo endTargetFactors="6.34;41.14" movePoint="0;7.30" startTargetFactors="91.13;39.41"/>
        </transition>
    </state>
    <state id="moving">
        <qt:editorinfo stateColor="#a508d0" geometry="425.83;344.53;-60;-50;120;100" scenegeometry="425.83;344.53;365.83;294.53;120;100"/>
        <transition type="internal" event="disconnect" target="unknown">
            <qt:editorinfo movePoint="2.08;17.72"/>
        </transition>
        <transition type="internal" event="stopped" target="ready">
            <qt:editorinfo endTargetFactors="68.30;90.08" movePoint="62.50;10.32" startTargetFactors="68.69;5.74"/>
        </transition>
    </state>
</scxml>
```

[image]

```py
import os
import time
from functools import partial
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtScxml
import numpy as np


class Client(QtCore.QObject):
    # Client signals
    sig_move_done = QtCore.Signal()
    sig_disconnected = QtCore.Signal()
    sig_connected = QtCore.Signal()

    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def client_move(self, dest):
        print(f"Client moving to {dest}...")
        time.sleep(3)  # some blocking function
        if np.random.rand() < 0.5:
            print("Error occurred during movement...")
            self.sig_disconnected.emit()
        else:
            print("Movement done...")
            self.sig_move_done.emit()

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def client_disconnect(self):
        # do something then...  on success do:
        self.sig_disconnected.emit()

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def client_connect(self):
        # do something ... on success do:
        self.sig_connected.emit()


class GUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("State")

        self.btn_move = QtWidgets.QPushButton("move")
        self.btn_connect = QtWidgets.QPushButton("(re-)connect")

        self.client = Client()
        self._thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self._thread.start()
        self.client.moveToThread(self._thread)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_move)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_connect)
        self.resize(320, 120)

        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "Simple_State_Machine.scxml")

        machine = QtScxml.QScxmlStateMachine.fromFile(filename)
        machine.setParent(self)

        for error in machine.parseErrors():
            print(error.toString())

        machine.connectToState("unknown", self, QtCore.SLOT("on_unknown_state_enter(bool)"))
        machine.connectToState("ready", self, QtCore.SLOT("on_ready_state_enter(bool)"))
        machine.connectToState("moving", self, QtCore.SLOT("on_moving_state_enter(bool)"))


        self.btn_connect.clicked.connect(partial(machine.submitEvent, "connect"))
        self.btn_move.clicked.connect(partial(machine.submitEvent, "move"))

        self.client.sig_disconnected.connect(partial(machine.submitEvent, "disconnect"))
        self.client.sig_connected.connect(partial(machine.submitEvent, "connect"))
        self.client.sig_move_done.connect(partial(machine.submitEvent, "stopped"))

        machine.start()

    @QtCore.Slot(bool)
    def on_unknown_state_enter(self, active):
        if active:
            print("unknown_state")
            self.btn_move.setDisabled(True)
            self.btn_connect.setEnabled(True)

    @QtCore.Slot(bool)
    def on_ready_state_enter(self, active):
        if active:
            print("ready_state")
            self.btn_move.setEnabled(True)
            self.btn_connect.setDisabled(True)

    @QtCore.Slot(bool)
    def on_moving_state_enter(self, active):
        if active:
            print("moving_state")
            self.btn_move.setDisabled(True)
            self.btn_connect.setDisabled(True)
            dest = np.random.randint(1, 100)
            wrapper = partial(self.client.client_move, dest)
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._thread.quit()
        self._thread.wait()
        super().closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = GUI()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, especially the 2nd approach looks nice, since I can graphically develop the FSM! Two follow up questions: Is there a reason you're using partial instead of lambda? In the meantime I read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819538/using-lambda-expression-to-connect-slots-in-pyqt that connecting signals/slots via lambda as I did above is probably not a good idea because of carbage collection problems. But I guess 'your' way is save. Are you aware of any existing tools to visualize SCXML during runtime? I kinda like the idea to see the state machine while the program is running.

Comment: @JulianS. 1) lambda generates some problems such as the one you point out among others, so I prefer to use functools.partial. 2) QtCreator comes with an SCXML editor: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-scxml.html and is the one that I used to build the .scxml

Comment: 1) ok. Good advice. 2) yes I got that, but I was thinking of showing the xml diagram during runtime to visualize what state the machine is in, as I did above with pytransitions, but it looks like QT has no inbuilt methods for that

Comment: @JulianS. no, maybe you can use pytransitions as an interface, or port that logic to Qt.

Comment: I just noticed that the first solution does block the Qt event loop, i.e. the GUI is frozen while the client is moving (e.g. you can't resize). There is again the workaround with having a sig_move_requested QSignal as a class attribute of the GUI class (connected to self.client.client_move) that is triggered inside on_moving_state_enter() but is there a more elegant way ?  I didn't check the 2nd solution yet, but my guess is it's the same.

Comment: @JulianS. mmm, it seems that it is a PySide2 bug, in PyQt5 it does not happen so when I tested it I did not realize the error, the easiest is what you point out: use signals.

Comment: interesting! I can confirm it works for me with PyQt5 as well..  I have no strong preference for PySide2, so I'm now using qtpy...

Comment: @JulianS. Unfortunately PySide2 has many bugs, and this seems to be one of them.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I thought since it's now officially supported by Qt, it might be the better choice. But I guess using qtpy doesn't hurt and will prepare me to use PySide2 once it's more reliable