# Why is Lambda used in this connection string?

Tags: python, lambda

Hello i am relatively new to coding and i found this piece of code on a website to use in my application but i don't know why the lambda function is used in this instance could someone help explain this to me so that i can annotate the code fully thank you very much.

```py
class QuizWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Load the UI file
        loadUi('QuizProject.ui', self)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)

        # Selected Subject
        self.subject = None
        self.selectedFont = None

        # Scroll Area
        self.scroll_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.scrollAreaQuiz.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollAreaQuiz.setLayout(self.scroll_layout)

        # Connections

        # pageHome Buttons
        self.btnLogout.clicked.connect(self.logout)
        self.btnSetting.clicked.connect(self.change_to_setting)
        self.btnTakeQuiz.clicked.connect(self.change_to_quiz_subjects)

        # pageSetting Buttons
        self.btnBack.clicked.connect(self.change_to_home)
        self.btnChgFont.clicked.connect(self.change_font)
        self.btnChgBgColor.clicked.connect(self.change_background_color)

        # pageQuizSubjects Buttons
        self.btnBack_2.clicked.connect(self.change_to_home)
        # Subject Buttons
        self.btnBiology.clicked.connect(lambda: self.change_to_quiz('Biology'))
        self.btnComputing.clicked.connect(lambda: self.change_to_quiz('Computing'))
        self.btnCustom.clicked.connect(lambda: self.change_to_quiz('Custom'))
        self.btnGeography.clicked.connect(lambda: self.change_to_quiz('Geography'))
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819538/using-lambda-expression-to-connect-slots-in-pyqt Does this answer your question? as it is currently, it's rather broad..

Answer (score 1):

`.clicked.connect(...)` takes a callable, and then calls it with no arguments. This is fine for `change_to_home()`, `change_font()`, `logout()`, etc., because those methods do not have any arguments anyway.

However, `change_to_quiz()` *does* take an argument. In order to get `clicked.connect()` to call it with an argument, we need to provide an intermediate layer that adds that argument. That's what the lambda does here - it is called with no arguments, and then passe sthrough to `change_to_quiz()` with the appropriate argument.